# How can I tell how many non-isomorphic unrooted trees with 6 edges exists without drawing them all?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, trees, graph-isomorphism

Typically my professor asks that we draw them all, but I would like to save some time to confirm how many I need.

Comment: By cheating: Find the number of trees with up to 5 edges by drawing them all, and stick the numbers you find into [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C6). This finds 116 sequences, the first of which is described as being what you want.

Comment: @Henning: That link returns $381$ sequences for me, of which [the second](http://oeis.org/A000055) is the right one.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Hm, I must have copied the wrong link. The one that finds 116 sequences is a search for `1,1,1,2,3,6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geng` which is packaged with [nauty](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/).

```
geng 7 6:6 -c -u
```

Trees with 6 edges have 7 vertices, and any connected 7-vertex graph with 6 edges must be a tree.  So we call geng to generate the 7-vertex connected (`-c`) graphs with 6 edges.  The `-u` means to count them.

```
>A geng -cd1D6 n=7 e=6
>Z 11 graphs generated in 0.00 sec
```

If you want the graphs themselves, we can redirect the output to a file

```
geng 7 6:6 -c > temp.txt
```

then use `showg` to print the adjacency lists:

```
showg temp.txt
```

Here's the output:

```
Graph 1, order 7.
  0 : 6;
  1 : 6;
  2 : 6;
  3 : 6;
  4 : 6;
  5 : 6;
  6 : 0 1 2 3 4 5;

Graph 2, order 7.
  0 : 5 6;
  1 : 6;
  2 : 6;
  3 : 6;
  4 : 6;
  5 : 0;
  6 : 0 1 2 3 4;

Graph 3, order 7.
  0 : 5 6;
  1 : 5;
  2 : 6;
  3 : 6;
  4 : 6;
  5 : 0 1;
  6 : 0 2 3 4;

Graph 4, order 7.
  0 : 5;
  1 : 5;
  2 : 6;
  3 : 6;
  4 : 6;
  5 : 0 1 6;
  6 : 2 3 4 5;

Graph 5, order 7.
  0 : 5 6;
  1 : 5;
  2 : 5;
  3 : 6;
  4 : 6;
  5 : 0 1 2;
  6 : 0 3 4;

Graph 6, order 7.
  0 : 4 6;
  1 : 5 6;
  2 : 6;
  3 : 6;
  4 : 0;
  5 : 1;
  6 : 0 1 2 3;

Graph 7, order 7.
  0 : 4 5;
  1 : 5 6;
  2 : 6;
  3 : 6;
  4 : 0;
  5 : 0 1;
  6 : 1 2 3;

Graph 8, order 7.
  0 : 4 6;
  1 : 5 6;
  2 : 5;
  3 : 6;
  4 : 0;
  5 : 1 2;
  6 : 0 1 3;

Graph 9, order 7.
  0 : 4 6;
  1 : 5;
  2 : 5;
  3 : 6;
  4 : 0;
  5 : 1 2 6;
  6 : 0 3 5;

Graph 10, order 7.
  0 : 3 6;
  1 : 4 6;
  2 : 5 6;
  3 : 0;
  4 : 1;
  5 : 2;
  6 : 0 1 2;

Graph 11, order 7.
  0 : 3 5;
  1 : 4 6;
  2 : 5 6;
  3 : 0;
  4 : 1;
  5 : 0 2;
  6 : 1 2;
```